# Android Custom ListView with Images and Text in horizantally

Tags: java, android, android-gallery

first of all sorry for poor communication, i have using custom array adapter and list of images and names are displaying  gridview control in my app.The images and names are come from sql server database now showing all images bind and display to gridview, i want to images displaying slide type i.e. first column display 3 images after click the image slide to the next 3 images display.. anybody help me please.

My Code is:

enquiryfrm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Name"/>
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/questionListSV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">


    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridviewimg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:stretchMode="none"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:paddingBottom="60dp"/>   
    </ScrollView>
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </Spinner>

</LinearLayout>
```

2.enquiryaimagetemplate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview2"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/not_available" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtitem_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="15sp" >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtregidno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="15sp" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

3.enquiryitems.java

```
public class enquiryItems {
        String itemname;
        int Reg_id;
        Bitmap itemimg;
        public enquiryItems(String itemname,Bitmap itemimg,int Reg_id){
            this.itemname=itemname;
            this.itemimg=itemimg;
            this.Reg_id=Reg_id;
        }

        public String getItemname(){
            return itemname;
        }
        public Bitmap getItemimg(){return itemimg;}
        public int getReg_id(){return  Reg_id;}
    }
```

4.enquiryarrayadapter

```
public class EnquiryArrayadapter extends ArrayAdapter<enquiryItems> {

    ArrayList<enquiryItems> itemlist = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;
    ConnectionClass connectionClass;
    public EnquiryArrayadapter(ArrayList<enquiryItems> objects,Context context)      {
        super(context,R.layout.enquiryaimagetemplate,objects);
        this.itemlist=objects;
        this.context=context;
        //visitorlist=objects;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return super.getCount();
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent){
        if (convertview == null) { // This a new view we inflate the new layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.enquiryaimagetemplate, parent, false);
        }

        connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();

        final TextView txtitem_name=(TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.txtitem_name);
        final TextView txtregidno = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.txtregidno);
        final ImageView imageview2 = (ImageView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.imageview2);
        final enquiryItems objitem=itemlist.get(position);
        imageview2.setImageBitmap(objitem.getItemimg());
        txtitem_name.setText(objitem.getItemname());
        txtregidno.setText(String.valueOf(objitem.getReg_id()));
      //  txtregidno.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        imageview2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //ImageView imageview2 = (ImageView) v;
                String idval = txtregidno.getText().toString();
               /* int id=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(idval));
                zoomImageFromThumb(imageview2, id);*/
            }
        });
        return convertview;

    }
```

5.enquiry.java

```
public class Enquiry  extends Fragment {
    ProgressDialog pbd;
    GridView gridviewimg;
    ConnectionClass connectionClass;
    int RegIdNo;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.enquiryfrm, container, false);
        connectionClass=new ConnectionClass();
        gridviewimg=(GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridviewimg);
        Fetch fe=new Fetch();
        fe.execute("");
        return rootView;
    }

    public class Fetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        String z = "";
        String ownid;
        ArrayList<enquiryItems> visitorList=new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pbd=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pbd.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            pbd.setCancelable(false);
            pbd.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r) {

            // pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (pbd.isShowing())
                pbd.dismiss();
            if(r!="empty"){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            EnquiryArrayadapter myAdapter=new EnquiryArrayadapter(visitorList,getActivity());
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            gridviewimg.setAdapter(myAdapter);
            //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
                } else {//
                    String query="";
                        query = "select * from FB_Feedback";


                    PreparedStatement ps2 = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
                    ArrayList data1 = new ArrayList();
                    while (rs2.next()) {

                        //Reg_Id=rs.getInt("Id");
                        RegIdNo = rs2.getInt("id");
                        String r = rs2.getString("Photo");
                        //Convertong Images string to bitmap
                        byte[] decodeString = Base64.decode(r, Base64.DEFAULT);
                        Bitmap decodebitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodeString, 0, decodeString.length);
                        visitorList.add(new enquiryItems("Item Name : "+rs2.getString("Feedback"),decodebitmap,RegIdNo));
                        //  }
                        //  z="Success";
                    }
                    if (RegIdNo==0){
                        z="No Visitor data";
                    }else {
                        z="empty";
                    }

                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                z = ex.toString();

            }
            return z;

        }
    }
```

like the below format need [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EO88.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not understandable. As far as I understood, try using [horizontal listview.](https://acadgild.com/blog/horizontal-listview-android/)

Comment: Hey you can use recyclerview for this

Comment: i want to gridview list display to custom list only i.e. 3 images after sliding another 3 images display to front of the screen

Comment: Look up this example http://www.androhub.com/android-staggered-and-horizontal-recyclerview/